# Matlab: save file with variabile in name

Tags: matlab

What i'm trying to achieve is something like

```
variable = 2000
imwrite(x,'xx\xx\name'+variable+'.tif','Compression','none');
```

Is there a way to achieve this in matlab?

Comment: You can concatenate char arrays with `['xx\xx\name' num2str(variable) '.tif']`. Note the use of `num2str` to convert the number to a char array.

Comment: are you sure we dont need anything else?
Like that it give me this error:
Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: if you _exactly_ copy what I wrote, it should work. You probably miss the first `[`

Comment: When i try to put what you suggested it tell me on num2str(variable): invalid syntax  A (') might be missing a closing ')'

Comment: I'm a dumb, i didnt put the space between 'xxx\name' and num2str...ty! it worked!